# Error: "false Transaction mined but execution failed" when trying to deploy my test coin

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, remix, binance

I was trying to deploy my contract to the Binance smart chain test network and it failed. A warning did appear before I proceeded saying:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

This resulted in my transaction failing with the status saying:

"false Transaction mined but execution failed"

Can someone help me understand what has happened here so I could resolve this.

my transaction hash is:

0xa5b74757993458699108dbd1d8e6b61a33a9a6e43d4784220438f7c2b941a919

Comment: It seems to be an error in the constructor. Can you provide the contract source code? It is impossible to determine the cause without examining it.

Comment: @ismael thanks for getting back to me. the code is here:
https://pastebin.com/AAsr0p2B

Answer (score 0):

The constructor uses the pancake's router address from bsc net

```
    constructor (address marketingWallet) {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
         _marketingWallet = payable(marketingWallet);
 
        //Pancake Swap V2 address
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
```

But that address `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E` doesn't have a contract on bsc testnet and the constructor will revert.

Comment: thanks for sharing your inputs here. Sorry for reaching you out of the blue. I was wondering if you could assist me with this. I am kind of not finding any information anywhere else.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/swap-for-tokens-with-bot-protection-enabled-bpenabled
Thanks a ton in advance.